# Can't login Django admin with valid user and password on development environment (runserver)

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I can't log into Django with my valid username and password.

Its giving me the standard error: "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

I have even tried to create a new admin with

`python manage.py createsuperuser`

but even then I can't log into the new staff account.

I checked and made sure that I have a django_session table in my database, but the expire_date and before today.

I am using Django 2.2

I haven't logged into this project in a few months so I am not sure if that has anything to do with it?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Maybe your browser has cookies off? Try with a clean browser profile. Also make sure `INSTALLED_APPS` is as it should be. Are you connecting to `localhost:8000`? Or is this on production? Are you certain the installation in which you're running `createsuperuser` is the same as the one you're connecting to with your browser?

Comment: @how do you know user and passwrod is valid .   go to database and change the password.